# GraphQL error when launching KeystoneJS application

Tags: mongodb, graphql, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, keystonejs

I just created a KeystoneJS using `yarn create keystone-app my-app`.

When I try to run it using `yarn dev` and browse to it I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot use GraphQLSchema "[object GraphQLSchema]" from another module or realm.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of other
relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version is installed.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions

Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.
    at instanceOf (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/instanceOf.js:28:13)
    at isSchema (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:36:34)
    at assertSchema (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/node_modules/graphql/type/schema.js:40:8)
    at validateSchema (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/node_modules/graphql/type/validate.js:44:28)
    at graphqlImpl (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js:79:62)
    at /my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js:28:59
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at graphql (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js:26:10)
    at _graphQLQuery.<computed> (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/lib/Keystone/index.js:477:7)
    at Keystone.executeQuery (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/lib/Keystone/index.js:252:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as onConnect] (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/initial-data.js:10:22)
    at /my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/lib/Keystone/index.js:323:35
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async executeDefaultServer (/my/home/path/my-first-ks-app/node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/bin/utils.js:114:3)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I am on Windows 10 / WSL (v1) with Ubuntu. KeystoneJS is running from Linux and MongoDB server is installed and running on Windows. This is because when I had it running in Linux, `mongod` showed as running and listening but I was not able to connect to it (via KeystoneJS or via shell using `mongo` command).

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: same problem here. 
The blank starter project seems to be working for now.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `graphql@15.0.0` when I got this error.

I fixed it by downgrading to `graphql@14.6.0`.

I got this issue on a keystone project with apollo.

Answer (score 1):

run this line

```
rm -rf node_modules/@keystonejs/keystone/node_modules/graphql
```

or add it to the Dockerfile for building image for production